# I need place contents of rows with positive results to a separate sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need place contents of rows with positive results to a separate sheet. Thinking an array formula, and VLOOKUP may work any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try simple:

```
=FILTER(A:A, A:A>0)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.